# relation between planes of a infinitesimal tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]In relation to the tetrahedron depicted, the book I'm reading says that this relation between its surfaces holds:

$d\sigma_i = d\sigma_n \cos(\mathbf{n}, x_i) = n_i d\sigma_m$

I don't understand how to derive it. If **n** is the unit exterior normal to the surface, (as the book defines it) then $n_i$ should be equal to 1, leading to $d\sigma_i = 1\cdot d\sigma_m$

Comment: I think $n_i$ is the component of $\mathbf{n}$ along axis $x_i$.